# On click, press enter to textbox

Tags: javascript, input, keycode

There is a combobox and if I click to an option, the value going to copied to a textbox. I want to writing these option values one under the other.

This is the javascript code:

```
$('#subcategory1').on('change', function() {
    $('#properties').val($('#properties').val() + '' + $(this).val() + ' ');
})
```

I tried with ' + keyCode==13', but it's not work.
Help me!

Comment: did you try with <br/> instead?

Comment: Do you mean textbox = div or p element? Or do you mean a textarea as a form element?

Comment: can you please attach whole file.

Comment: you have to use <br/> with html(), not val() method

Comment: Please explain your problem better and include the HTML markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example if you want to add the value of the subcategory element to a `textarea`. You can use the newline character `\n` instead of the HTML element `<br>`

```
$('#subcategory1').on('change', function() {
    $('#properties').val($('#properties').val() + "\n" + $(this).val());
});
```

HTML:

```
<textarea name="properties" id="properties"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

So there are two ways to archieve that.

The first way would be to use the `ul`-List-Tag and append `li`-Child-Tags to them with the clicked value.

But if you want to use the textbox, you have to seperate the current value with the new ones and add `\n` returns between them.

**HTML**

```
Select your products: 

<select id="products">
    <option>iPhone</option>
    <option>PC</option>
    <option>Xbox One</option>
    <option>Stack Underflow</option>
    <option>Someone your like</option>
</select>

<br>
<br>

Your selected products:

<br>
<br>

<ul id="selected_products"></ul>

<textarea id="selected_products_textarea"></textarea>
```

**javascript - One script to rule them all**

```
var ul = document.getElementById('selected_products');
var textarea = document.getElementById('selected_products_textarea')

document.getElementById('products').onchange = function() {

    // UL List Part
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = this.value;

    ul.appendChild(li);

    // Textarea Part
    textarea.innerHTML = textarea.innerHTML.length == 0 ? this.value : textarea.innerHTML + '\n' + this.value;

}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kuwc6kte/1/

Now you can go further and remove the selected item from the select list or check if the current selected option is already in the list and go on.. whatever your requirements are in your script.

---

**EDIT**

Just saw you using jQuery, here a jQuery Solution with the same **HTML**:

**jQuery**

```
var ul = $('#selected_products');
var textarea = $('#selected_products_textarea');

$('#products').on( 'change', function() {

    // UL List Part
    var li = $('</li>');
    li.html( $(this).val() );

    ul.append(li);

    // Textarea Part
    textarea.html( textarea.html().length == 0 ? $(this).val() : textarea.html() + '\n' + $(this).val() );

});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kuwc6kte/3/